# Используя паттерн в matches -В ошибке постоянно показывает на последний символ

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения, шаблоны-проектирования

Всем привет, проблема, такова- при использовании паттерна в методе matches() -в ошибке показывает на последний символ

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
       if(scanLine.matches(
    "^((LABEL ([a-z]([[a-z]|[\\d])|\\d{0,4}))(, ([a-z]([[a-z]|[\\d])|\\d{0,4}))*)$")) 
System.out.println("Строка записана правильно");
```

Comment: В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Проверен паттерн на сайте: https://regex101.com/r/OiIJId/2

Comment: Запятую сразу после скобки экранируйте: `(, -> (\,`.

Comment: kff, в джаве пишет, что нельзя использовать одну косую- поставил две, ошибка осталась :\

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Проблема с повторением цифр в регулярном выражении Java](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/596527/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%84%d1%80-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-java)

Answer (score -1):

думаю так будет лучше:

```
"^((LABEL ([a-z]([a-z]|[\\d])|\\d{0,4}))(, ([a-z]([a-z]|[\\d])|\\d{0,4}))*)$"
```

непонятно, зачем дважды используется двойная квадратная скобка